# Extract nodes from xml based on keywords

Tags: xml, shell, xpath

I have an XML like below and am trying to extract the nodes based on a keyword.
Tried using XPath and XMLLint. But obviously, I'm not doing something right. So
hoping for some help in this regard.

XML File

```
  <section>
    <h>2 Introduction</h1>
    <region>Intro 1</region>
    <region>Background</region>
  </section>
<article>
 <body>
  <section>
    <h1>2 Task objectives</h1>
    <region>2.1 Primary objectives </region>
    <region>2.</region>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2>Requirements</h1>
    <region>System Requirements </region>
    <region>Technical Requirements</region>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h3>Design</h1>
    <region>Design methodology </region>
    <region>Design patterns</region>
  </section>
  </body>
</article>
```

Given this XML and a keyword `Task objectives` or `objectives` (Case
insensitive), I need to extract the entire node and write to another XML file

```
<section>
    <h1>2 Task objectives</h1>
    <region>2.1 Primary objectives </region>
    <region>2.</region>
</section>
```

The extraction piece I tried using Xpath and XMllint.

```
 $ xmllint --xpath //body//section//h1[.="Task objectives"] Prior.mod.xml
 XPath error : Invalid predicate
//body//section//h1[.=Task objectives]
                  ^
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
XPath evaluation failure
```

Could anyone please let me know what is wrong with the above and how I can fix
it? Also, I'd like to do this in a shell on a directory of files. Is XMLlint the
best option?

Answer (score 2):

The shell is removing the quote (`"`) characters during command-line parsing -- you need to quote the entire expression, as in

```
xmllint --xpath '//body//section//h1[.="Task objectives"]' Prior.mod.xml
```

Example:

```
$ xmllint --xpath //body//section//h1[.="Task objectives"] -
<body>
<section>
<h1>Task objectives</h1>
<h1>abcd</h1>
</section>
</body>
^D
```

Resulting in :

```
XPath error : Invalid predicate
//body//section//h1[.=Task objectives]
                           ^
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
XPath evaluation failure
```

Note the missing quotes. I then tried

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//body//section//h1[.="Task objectives"]' -
<body>
<section>
<h1>Task objectives</h1>
<h1>abcd</h1>
</section>
</body>
^D
```

which produced the output

```
<h1>Task objectives</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with XPath 1.0:

```xpath
//section[contains(
  translate(h1, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
  'task objectives')
]
```